# Why use a bare repository for config dotfiles?

Tags: git

I have read this article, describing how to use git and configure dot files over many computers:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles

The author uses a bare repository and changes the working directory to $HOME for the dot files. 
Why does the author use a bare repository in this context? Could you just not take a normal repository and set the WORK_DIR to the $HOME directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed do that.

It's not clear to me why the author chose to do that, but in general, making your home directory a Git repository means you have to ignore almost all files by default and either add exceptions or add new files with `git add -f`, or else *every file anywhere under your home directory* will be considered an untracked file in your repository.  Using a bare repo with a special alias means that by default, your home directory won't be considered a repository, avoiding all those problems.

Another option that you can use is to use a normal repository located elsewhere and have a script or Makefile to copy the files into place.

Comment: Good answer.  Another side effect is things like `git status` can be really slow as it will crawl through your entire home folder too.

Answer (score 1):

Using bare repo like that, can aovid caring lots of unknow files under your $HOME

I prefer this:

```
mkdir ~/dotF
cd ~/dotF
git init
```

then put files I know in the stand alone folder, and set some soft-links.
Just like a U-disk